# MYSQL Crash on building Full Text Search Index

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I need help and Guidance. I am using XAMPP local server.

I tried to create a Full Text search index using below command:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX corp_nz ON corp_news(content ASC, subject ASC);
```

The table corp_news has around 91000 records with 7 columns.

When I fire this query, in phpmyadmin, i see a popup message saying "mysqld.exe is not working"

Surprisingly,when i run the same query on a subset of corp_news table with only 10,000 records, the there is no Error message, It work just fine.

May someone please Please help me through this?

My Server config is as below:

```
Server version: 10.1.9-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=2
max_threads=1001
thread_count=2
```

The MySQL Error log is:

```html
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5088 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\mysql\db'
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [ERROR] mysql.db: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\tables_priv' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\mysql\tables_priv'
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [ERROR] mysql.tables_priv: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\columns_priv' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\mysql\columns_priv'
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [ERROR] mysql.columns_priv: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\procs_priv' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [Warning] Checking table:   '.\mysql\procs_priv'
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [ERROR] mysql.procs_priv: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
2016-03-17  1:06:17 5604 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.9-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2016-03-17  1:07:48 4904 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Start
2016-03-17  1:07:48 4904 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Start reading clustered index of the table and create temporary files
2016-03-17  1:07:48 4904 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : End of reading clustered index of the table and create temporary files
2016-03-17  1:07:49 4904 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Completed
2016-03-17  1:46:13 7868 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Start
2016-03-17  1:46:13 7868 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Start reading clustered index of the table and create temporary files
2016-03-17 01:46:14 17a4  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 6052 in file row0merge.cc line 892
InnoDB: Failing assertion: b < &block[srv_sort_buf_size]
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
160317  1:46:14 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see http://kb.askmonty.org/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.9-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=2
max_threads=1001
thread_count=2
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787099 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
mysqld.exe!my_mb_ctype_mb()
mysqld.exe!?set_charset@String@@QAEXPBUcharset_info_st@@@Z()
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MySQL bug reports system:

This issue has been fixed in 5.6.31, 5.7.13 release, and here's the changelog entry:

> An ALTER TABLE operation that added a full-text index raised an
>   assertion due to a length mismatch.

While the log entry is about alter table, I think it is related. Can you try on one of the supposedly fixed versions?

If not, as a workaround I found out that I can dump the table, truncate it, then add the index and then import the data back.

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug of Mariadb/Mysql/Percona
You can try to increase sort buffer size (sometimes it helped).

Even Mariadb 10.1.10 reports, that the bug was fixed, it is still crashing our server in 10.1.18.